# Add const qualifier to array reference typedef

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, typedef

Consider the following type definition:

```
typedef int (&foo_t)[3];
```

or

```
using foo_t = int(&)[3];
```

When adding a const qualifier to the type, it is ignored:

```
int foo[3] = {1, 2, 3};
const foo_t fooref = foo;
fooref[0] = 4;  // No error here
```

Or when I try to assign a const array to it:

```
const int foo[3] = {1, 2, 3};
const foo_t fooref = foo;
/* error: binding reference of type ‘foo_t’ {aka ‘int (&)[3]’} to ‘const int [3]’ discards qualifiers
 const foo_t fooref = foo;
                      ^~~ */
```

**How can I add `const` to a typedef'ed array reference?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply add a `const` to the type referenced by a typedefed type. Think of typedefing a pointer type:

```
typedef int* pint_t;
```

The type `const pint_t` names an unmodifiable pointer to a modifiable `int`.

If you can, simply add it to the definition (or define a `const` variant of your type):

```
typedef const int (&foo_t)[3];
```

or

```
using foo_t = const int(&)[3];
```

If that's out of the question, a general unpacking scheme to make the inner-most type `const` may be implementable, but probably not advisable - i.e. check your design.